# Flutter have one scaffold with same body and bottom navigation bar but different appbars and have a button on one of them which toggles its state

Tags: flutter, button, visibility, appbar, bottom-navigation-bar

I have a Flutter app. On the main screen, it has an appbar, body, and bottomnavigation bar. On the bottom are four icons to flip through the different screens. One of the screens has an icon on the top that flips between regular view and favorites view by tapping on the icon.

When I tap on the icon, it changes color to indicate it is in favorite mode. It uses setstate to do this, and the bottomnavigationbar also uses state. However, when I tap on the favorites icon, the bottomnavigationbar disappears. I am not sure why that is occurring.   How can I correct this?

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I already tried:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '/screens/adoptGrid.dart';
import '/screens/breedList.dart';
import '/screens/fit.dart';

StreamController<int> buttonChangedHighlight =
    StreamController<int>.broadcast();
var buttonChangedHighlightStream = buttonChangedHighlight.stream;

void main() async {
  runApp(const SplashPage());
}

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

final RouteObserver<ModalRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute>();

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Get.off(const HomeScreen(title: 'Feline Finder')));
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Feline Finder',
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: Center(
            child: Image.asset("assets/Full/Launch.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.center),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool favoritesSelected = false;

  static List<Widget> pages = <Widget>[
    Fit(),
    BreedList(title: "Breed List"),
    AdoptGrid(),
    Container(color: Colors.orange)
  ];

// 9
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget? getLeadingButtons(selectedIndex) {
    if (selectedIndex == 2) {
      return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            var _favoritesSelected = (favoritesSelected) ? false : true;
            setState(() {
              favoritesSelected = _favoritesSelected;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: (favoritesSelected) ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
            size: 40,
          ));
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Feline Finder"),
          leading: getLeadingButtons(_selectedIndex)),
      body: pages[_selectedIndex],
      // 4
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        // 5
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).textSelectionTheme.selectionColor,
        // 10
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        // 11
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        // 6
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Fit',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            label: 'Breeds',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.card_membership),
            label: 'Adopt',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show us the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because , you miss `backgroundColor:` value in `BottomNavigationBarItem`

in first `BottomNavigationBarItem`

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Fit',
          ),
```

you set `backgroundColor: Colors.grey` in first `BottomNavigationBarItem`, but in next `BottomNavigationBarItem` you don't set `backgroundColor` for it

Add color for background will fix this:

```
items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Fit',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            label: 'Breeds',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.card_membership),
            label: 'Adopt',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: 'Favorites',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ],
```